# How to delete bs4.element.Tag element in Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a Python list which is

```
url_list = [<img src="https://test.com/temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>, <img src="https://test.com/not_temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>]
```

both element in that list are 'bs4.element.Tag' type.

**How do I delete `'<img src="https://test.com/temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>'` element while keeping its 'bs4.element.Tag' type?**

and the list will keep changing in time, so `del url_list[0]` is not going to work.

I tried `url_list.remove('<img src="https://test.com/temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>')`

but it didn't work since its type was different.

Edit:
I want to remove this `'<img src="https://test.com/temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>'` exact element. and "while keeping its 'bs4.element.Tag' type" means i dont want change the list element's type.

Comment: **`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`**  Your "code" is incorrect python. Please provide a [mcve] that replicates your problem and the code that tries to solve it.

Comment: Do you want to remove that specific item or all items with some property? In the latter case, what is that property? And what does it mean "while keeping its 'bs4.element.Tag' type"?

Comment: @DYZ yes I want to remove that specific item. and I don't want to change list element's type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string representation of the tag into a BS object:

```
tag = '<img src="https://test.com/temp.jpg" style="display:block"/>'
unwanted = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tag).img
```

And remove it:

```
url_list.remove(unwanted)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I get 'No parser was explicitly specified' warning. How do i prevent it?

Comment: It is not an error but a warning, but you can specify a parser:  `bs4.BeautifulSoup(tag, 'lxml')`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing is probably to simply go through every tag and check whether or not a tag contains a certain element, which you can do with the `tag.get()` method. For example, you could do something along the lines of

```
 for tag in url_list:
     if tag.get('src') == 'some_url':
         url_list.remove(tag)
```

the `get()` method can be used to extract any of the individual properties of the tag, not just the src. How you filter out what tag to remove is then up to you.

Comment: This is very bad (and incorrect) advice: one should not modify the list that is being iterated.